# Typescript convert an array to JSON

Tags: json, typescript

I have a complicated data structure that I need to convert to JSON.  The problem is that my field names and values are in an array.

For instance, I have the following (simplified from my code base):

```
let SampleData = [
        { Field: 'Key', Value: '7'},
        { Field: 'City', Value: 'Some City'},
        { Field: 'Description', Value: 'Some Description'}
];
```

Basically my data is an array where the first element is the database column name, and the second element is the data in the column.  I am trying to get a JSON object that is:

```
{ Key: 7, City: 'Some City', Description: 'Some Description' }
```

My real code has the fields and data is structures within the object, so I cannot simply use an Object.create() or Object.assign() as far as I can get working.

I have tried looping through to build a simple string and then use the JSON.parse to break it apart, but this seems like a lot of overhead for something I would have thought would be simpler.

Comment: Try this: maping the array to an object `var obj = {}; array.forEach(item =&gt; obj[item.Field] = item.Value);` and then converting the object to json `JSON.strignify(obj)`

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.  You did get this in before the answer below, which also works.

Comment: @SevenScott Glad to have helped you! I just posted my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you asked, here's how to do it:

1. Mapping the array to an object
2. Converting the object to JSON

```js
let array = [{
    Field: 'Key',
    Value: '7'
  },
  {
    Field: 'City',
    Value: 'Some City'
  },
  {
    Field: 'Description',
    Value: 'Some Description'
  }
];

// #1 Mapping the array to an object...
let obj = {};
array.forEach(item => obj[item.Field] = item.Value);

// #2 Converting the object to JSON...
let json = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(json);
```

**Bonus (ES6 + reduce):**

```
const obj = array.reduce((acc, { Field, Value }) => ({ ...acc, [Field]: Value }), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below approach . I have used spread operator(ES6) and Object.assign to create the object ,then converted it into json string.

```js
        let SampleData = [
                { Field: 'Key', Value: '7'},
                { Field: 'City', Value: 'Some City'},
                { Field: 'Description', Value: 'Some Description'}
        ];
        
    let obj = Object.assign(...SampleData.map( x => Object.values(x)).map(y => ({[y[0]]: y[1]})));
    console.log(obj);
   //{ Key: "7", City: "Some City", Description: "Some Description" }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and here is how I achieved it.

```js
var ranges: segmentRange[] = new Array(2);
ranges[0] = { minimumPercentage: 50, maximumPercentage: 60 };
ranges[1] = { minimumPercentage: 30, maximumPercentage: 40 };        
const segmentRanges = { segmentRanges: ranges };
return JSON.stringify(segmentRanges);
```

**Output:**

{"segmentRanges":[{"minimumPercentage":50,"maximumPercentage":60},{"minimumPercentage":30,"maximumPercentage":40}]}

HTH,