# Assign array to JSON object as a new object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an array which includes some values, ex.

```
let array = [value1, value2];
```

How can I create a JSON object like the following?

```
{
  "field": "[value1, value2]"
}
```

Comment: Have you looking for before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101176/typescript-convert-an-array-to-json Good Luck.

Comment: Just don't ask anything. Search before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101176/typescript-convert-an-array-to-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript convert an array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101176/typescript-convert-an-array-to-json)

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do. I want the format as I described it. The answer is given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` method:

```
let array = [value1, value2];
let yourJObject={"field":JSON.stringify(array)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` for output a json, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

I think you could find it pretty easily with a Google search :)

```js
const result = JSON.stringify({ field: ["toto", "tutu"]})
console.log(result)
```